# Format character prefix onto data in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, format-string

I have a query where I am trying to add a prefix to week numbers.
Right now, the query puts out the week numbers as (1,2,3,4...) Is there a way where I can add "Wk" to the beginning of the week number for the entire row? (ex: Wk 1)
'''FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%m-%d-%Y', CAST( ttl.insert_timestamp AS DATE)) AS Cycle_Time,
EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM ttl.insert_timestamp) AS Week,
FROM `tableName` ttl'''

Comment: have a look, at how to post questions in a better way.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
CONCAT("Wk ", CAST(EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM ttl.insert_timestamp) AS STRING)) AS Week
```